# SQL Server : list months between range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to calculate the values of financial hedges but I want the input to be as simple as possible. So for example, I have a contract with a quantity of 1,000 per month from 2/1/2017 to 12/31/2018 (it won't always be this date range, it could be 1 month or 3+ years) with a strike price of $3. I want to enter just 1 row of data into 4 columns: [Volume],[Start],[End],[Strike].

The issue is I need to multiply the 2017 data by one price and the 2018 by a different price. The easy answer would be to enter a row for 2017 and a row for 2018 but I don't want to do this because I may have 50 or more contracts to enter in and I want to do as little input as possible.

I would use two columns [Year],[Price] from a price table. It would look like [2017],[4.50] and [2018],[5.25]. I can easily modify this to be monthly instead of annual if it helps simplify things.

I need the final calculation to be along the lines of:

```
2017: 11,000 * (3 - 4.50) = -$16,500
2018: 12,000 * (3 - 5.25) = -$27,000
Total value = -$43,500
```

So my question is, how can I get a count of months for each year in the range?

I would like the output to be something like

```
2017, 11
2018, 12
```

Comment: All you want is to count the amount of months by year in a date range?

Comment: Will contracts always start/end at beginning/end of month, or can they be mid-month?

Comment: @JorgeCampos Yes, I believe that is all I want.

Comment: @HartCO They should all be full months, starting at the first day and ending on the last day of the month.

Answer (score 1):

Calendar tables can be helpful in situations like this, there are many sample scripts out there, here is one: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

You could also simply use year and month in your `price` table and join on the range, an Integer type `Year_Month_Int` field could be used '201601, 201602, 201603...`

Then:

```
SELECT *
FROM contracts c
JOIN prices p
  ON p.Year_Month_Int BETWEEN (YEAR(c.start)*100)+MONTH(c.start) AND (YEAR(c.end)*100)+MONTH(c.end)
```

If you included the integer version year-month for `start` and `end` in the `contracts` table you could simplify the `JOIN` criteria.

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a shot on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant on how to count the number of months in a range would be:

Setup:

```
create table soTest(
  id integer not null auto_increment,
  start_date datetime,
  end_date datetime,
  primary key (id)
);

insert into soTest (start_date, end_date) values 
    ('2017-02-01 00:00:00','2018-12-31 00:00:00');
```

Query:

```
select distinct case when extract(year from start_date) = yr 
            then format(datediff(concat(yr,'-12-31'), start_date)/30,0)
            else format(datediff(end_date, concat(yr,'-01-01'))/30,0) end as qtyMonths,
       yr
  from (select s.*, extract(year from start_date) yr from soTest s
         union all
        select s.*, extract(year from end_date) yr from soTest s
       ) a;
```

Result:

```
qtyMonths   yr
  11       2017
  12       2018
```

Be aware that this technique will only count the months in case of one registry. To get data from your contracts you would have to JOIN this with your dataset tables.